# Extraer datos de un array

Tags: php, array, variables, curl, get

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
if (!$curld = curl_init($dominio)) {
    echo "Could not initialize cURL session.\n";
    exit;
}
curl_setopt($curld, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_exec($curld);
echo "<pre>";
print_r(curl_getinfo($curld));
echo "</pre>";
```

y esto me devuelve algo como lo siguiente:

```
Array
(
    [url] => HTTP://google.es/
    [content_type] => text/html; charset=UTF-8
    [http_code] => 301
    [header_size] => 320
    [request_size] => 48
    [filetime] => -1
    [ssl_verify_result] => 0
    [redirect_count] => 0
    [total_time] => 0.061777
    [namelookup_time] => 0.028212
    [connect_time] => 0.029891
    [pretransfer_time] => 0.029907
    [size_upload] => 0
    [size_download] => 218
    [speed_download] => 3528
    [speed_upload] => 0
    [download_content_length] => 218
    [upload_content_length] => 0
    [starttransfer_time] => 0.061749
    [redirect_time] => 0
    [redirect_url] => http://www.google.es/
    [primary_ip] => 216.58.201.131
    [certinfo] => Array
        (
        )

    [primary_port] => 80
    [local_ip] => 185.177.153.145
    [local_port] => 56992
)
```

Me interesaría almacenar algunos datos de este array en variables por ejemplo:

```
$size_download = curl_getinfo([size_download ]);
```

Pero no me funciona no se como hacerlo.
¿Alguien me ayuda?

Gracias

Answer (score 1):

Según he comprobado en la [documentación oficial de php](http://php.net/manual/es/function.curl-getinfo.php), tienes un error en la línea de `$size_download = curl_getinfo([size_download]);`, ya que la sintaxis correcta para obtener el `size_download` sería algo así:

```
$size_download = curl_getinfo($curld, CURLINFO_SIZE_DOWNLOAD);
```

Answer (score 0):

Podrías declarar una variable para curl_exec.

```
$datos = curl_getinfo(curl_exec($curld));
```

y obtenerlo

```
$size_download = $datos['size_download'];
```

Comment: Gracias,lo he intentado así pero no me da el resultado, me devuelve algo como:
size download: <

y si intento con un numero:
$size_download = $datos['12'];
echo "size download: ". $size_download;
me duevuelve lo siguiente: 

size download: T

estoy cerca pero no lo tengo... Gracias

Comment: prueba con $datos = curl_getinfo(curl_exec($curld));

Comment: gracias por la pronta respuesta, de este modo:
$datos = curl_getinfo(curl_exec($curld));
$size_download = $datos['$size_download'];
echo "size download: ". $size_download;

$datos = curl_getinfo(curl_exec($curld));

size download: 
osease, nada, está vacía la varible

Comment: sigo sin solución para esto, alguien me podría ayudar??
gracias